# Loading a Silverlight Page on a Existing Page

Tags: silverlight, controls

I'm a Little bit new in Silverlight, so I'm checking if it posible to load a existing Silverlight Page (XAML) on another page, I'm not sure if something like and iframe or a panel control exists so i just tell it "Load this page" using their properties.

I will be waiting for your responses :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just include it like any other control in XAML. No need for something like a frame.

```xml
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <!-- Load another page -->
    <local:MyPage />
</Grid>
```